# How to pass application printf messages to /var/log/messages

Tags: c, kernel, printk, printf-debugging

I want to pass application printf log messages to the /var/log/messages.
Because kernel debug messages can be visible to /var/log/messages.But i am not getting how to pass application printf log messages to the /var/log/messages.
Can anyone please suggest me how to do this.

Comment: `printf()` prints to `stdout`.  It's just about the worst "logging" mechanism possible, especially for long-lived processes.  If you want to print to `/var/adm/messages`, see the man page for `syslog()`:  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html

Answer (score 3):

Change from, for example:

```
printf("The error was %s\n", strerror(errno));
```

to:

```
syslog(LOG_ERR, "The error was %s", strerror(errno));
```

Note that syslog is always sent a complete line at a time (and no need for `\n`).

For more control over your logging options use the `openlog()` function before any calls to `syslog()`.   See the openlog man page for more details.

Syslog routes messages based on the message ***priority*** -- the first argument to `syslog` (eg `LOG_ERR` in the sample above) -- and the ***facility***.  The facility either set in a call to `openlog()` or it defaults to `LOG_USER`.  The basic syntax of the syslog configuration file is lines of the form:

```
selector[;selector]     destination
```

where selector is:

```
facility[,facility].priority
```

(facility and/or priority can be the wildcard `*`).  A priority implicitly includes all higher priorities.

The destination can be a file, a remotehost, a program or a (list of) users.  Some examples:

```
*.*                   ihateyou             -- every message sent to this user
*.debug               *                    -- to every logged in user!
*.emerg               root,bob,tom         -- emergencies to these three
*.err                 /var/log/all-errors  -- all LOG_ERR and above to this file
cron.info             |/some/program       -- pipe these to /some/program
user.*                @some.host.com       -- send these to this host
cron,user.crit        /this/file           -- an example with multiple facilities
lpr.err;ftp.warn      /other/file          -- an example with multiple selectors
```

There may be some additional options, (eg, "none" as priority, a specific priority like =warn, and negation like !=warn), see your syslog.conf manpage for details on those.

See your syslog configuration file (usually /etc/syslog.conf) for how your system is routing its syslog messages.  Note: some systems run a variant of syslog like `nsyslog` or `rsyslog` -- these have more options and hence a potentially more complex configuration file.

The known facilities are: LOG_AUTH, LOG_AUTHPRIV, LOG_CRON, LOG_DAEMON, LOG_FTP, LOG_KERN, LOCAL_LOCAL0 .. LOG_LOCAL7, LOG_LPR, LOG_MAIL, LOG_NEWS, LOG_SYSLOG, LOG_USER, LOG_UUCP.  (LOG_KERN is not available to user processes)  Generally, one of LOG_DAEMON, LOG_LOCAL*n* or LOG_USER is usually the best choice.

The known priorities (also called severities) are (highest to lowest): LOG_EMERG, LOG_ALERT, LOG_CRIT, LOG_ERR, LOG_WARNING, LOG_NOTICE, LOG_INFO, LOG_DEBUG.